# Change menu name Odoo9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I'm inherit project module, how in my custom module in .xml view change menu title from Project to Project 1234

Original code from project menu:

```
 <!-- Top menu item -->
 <menuitem name="Project"
   id="base.menu_main_pm"
   groups="group_project_manager,group_project_user"
   icon="fa-calendar"
   web_icon="project,static/description/icon.png"
   sequence="50"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
<record model="ir.ui.menu" id="base.menu_main_pm">
  <field name="name">Project 1234</field>
</record>
```